# What is the equivalent of an NSDictionary in C#?

Tags: c#

What is the equivalent of an NSDictionary in C#?

Is it a collection?

Comment: Caught me off guard -- usually the question is the other way around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)
To set an object (like `setObject:forKey:`) you use:

```
Dictionary[Key] = Object;
```

To get an object (like `objectForKey:`) you use:

```
var Object = Dictionary[Key];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the HashTable Class:

Example :

```
HashTable dict = new HashTable();

dict.Add("key", object);
```